# How to know the direction of force resulted from pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

I understand that the resultant force from pressure is always perpendicular to the object, but I am not sure in which direction. It can be perpendicular to the left or to the right.

Here for example in explaining Bernoullie's effect I do not understand why the force P1A1 is to the right and the force P2A2 is to the left and not the opposite.

[Serway physics for scientists and angineers-8E, p415, Bernoullie's principle](https://preview.ibb.co/j0BDEw/IMG_20171228_131337.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of water is lying on top of this small volume. All this water pushes down on the volume and causes pressure on it. Was there no other water (or other fluid) on top of it then there would be no pressure on it.

So, therefore the volume is being compressed. This means that a pressure is acting **on** the volume from the surroundings, and due to Newton's 3rd law we know that an equal pressure is acting on the surroundings **from** the volume. when modelling the volume itself only external forces/pressures are included and not those caused by the volume.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an imaginary boundary between fluid in the region to the left and fluid in the region to the right, the fluid to the left exerts a pressure force on the fluid to the right in the direction from left to right; and the fluid to the right exerts an equal and opposite pressure force on the fluid to the left in the direction from right to left.  So if A exerts a pressure force on B, it is in the direction from A to B.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are determining the pressure on the outside of your object (a volume of fluid). This pressure acts perpendicular to the boundary, away from the gas exerting it, thus to the inside of the object you are considering.